# Find all ways to insert given char in a list

Tags: python, list, recursion, backtracking

I have the following list `["?","?","?,"?"]` and i want to find all the ways to insert `*` n times and the other indexes will be `"-"`
for example for n = 3 i'll get `[['*', '*', '*', '-'], ['*', '*', '-', '*'], ['*', '-', '*', '*'], ['-', '*', '*', '*']]`

I worte this

```
def backtrack(lst, index_lst, res, number, index=0):
    if index == len(index_lst):
       if lst.count("*") == number:
           lst_copy = lst.copy()
           res.append(lst_copy)
       return
    lst[index] = "*"
    backtrack(lst, index_lst, res, number, index + 1)
    lst[index] = "-"
    backtrack(lst, index_lst, res, number, index + 1)
    lst[index] = "?"


res1 = []
backtrack(["?", "?", "?","?"], [0, 1, 2,3], res1, 3)
```

And that's works but with big lists it takes huge amount of time any suggestions how can I make it more efficent?

by the way the index list is essential because I want to preform it on lists like that `["?","*","?"]` or `["?","-","?"]`  also, so I need to where there is `?`

**And without using any module**

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how you arrive at lists of length 4 from your input `['?', '?', '?']` when inserting `'*'` 3 times?

Comment: my mistake it was suppose to be`["?","?","?,"?"]`

Comment: Why can't you use modules in the standard library?

Comment: Because thats an exercise I got to practice backtracking

Comment: `with big lists it takes huge amount of time` -> can you be a bit more specific? What number does "big" entail and what amount of time do you consider "huge"? What is the expected time you need for a given `n` and where is this at currently?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for the permutations of a list.

```py
L = ["-","*","*","*"]
print(list(itertools.permutations(L)))
```

Comment: Any other way without itertools?